# Bower bug in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, bower

I'm trying to install latest stable release of bootstrap into my .NET Core web project using built-in Bower. I have bower.json file and put specific version of bootstrap here. Bower install the latest Bootstrap 4 alpha version.

[image]

Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be to clean the cache and remove the bower_components folder. Then, run install command with.

```
bower cache clean
bower install
```